# Convert string to array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a string like this:

```
"[\"fr\", \"sv\"]"
```

and I want to convert this string into an array like following.

```
["fr", "sv"]
```

I tried too many thing but not getting the expected outcome. Can anyone help?

Comment: The string is valid JSON. Is that always guaranteed? Where does it come from? Can you modify the source to make sure that it is always valid JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"[\"fr\", \"sv\"]"` - This is JSON-string array.

You should parse string as json:

```rb
require 'json'
# => true
JSON.parse("[\"fr\", \"sv\"]")
# => ["fr", "sv"]
```

Reverse process:

```rb
require 'json'
# => true
["fr", "sv"].to_json
# => "[\"fr\",\"sv\"]"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string looks like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), therefore I would use a JSON parser:

```
require 'json'
string = "[\"fr\", \"sv\"]"

JSON.parse(string)
#=> ["fr", "sv"]
```

Comment: Your answer was a little earlier.